# How can I find out the name of this street?

Tags: united-states, census-records, 1940s, palaeography, address

The image below comes from a page from the 1940 US Census:

[image]

(Full size image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDbNc.png).)

The page header from the Census is a poor scan. While I can make out the location as Washington DC, I'm unsure as to the ward:

[image]

(Full size image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA2Le.jpg).)

Can anyone decipher the street, either from the scan or deductively based on the information in the Census header?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried looking on nearby census sheets? The same street name often appears on multiple sheets, where it might be clearer.

**UPDATE**

I looked on the DC map near 8th and Underwood (some of the first streets in the enumeration district of your image) and spotted [Rittenhouse street](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=721+Rittenhouse+Street+Northwest,+Washington+D.C.,+DC&hl=en&ll=38.965165,-77.023451&spn=0.009009,0.012445&sll=38.964954,-77.015685&sspn=0.009009,0.012445&t=h&hnear=721+Rittenhouse+St+NW,+Washington,+District+of+Columbia+20011&z=16). I bet that's what that is.

Comment: +1 I'm in for Rittenhouse street also. If in doubt, are you able to locate a city directory?

Comment: As a potential starting point, this [ancestry.com search](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=USDirectories&rank=1&new=1&so=3&MSAV=1&msT=1&gss=ms_r_db&gsln_x=XO&msrpn__ftp=Washington%2C+District+Of+Columbia%2C+District+of+Columbia%2C+USA&msrpn=6076&msrpn_PInfo=8-%7C0%7C1652393%7C0%7C2%7C3244%7C11%7C0%7C890%7C6076%7C0%7C&msrpn_x=XO&msrpn__ftp_x=1&msydy=1939&msydy_x=1&gskw=+rittenhouse&gskw_x=1&dbOnly=_F00057B9%7C_F00057B9_x&uidh=pqh) identifies some people who lived on Rittenhouse in 1939 from the DC directory.

Comment: The One-Step finder "Obtaining Streets within EDs for the 1940 Census in One Step (Large Cities)" confirms there is a  street in ED 1-218 named "Rittenhouse NW".
 http://stevemorse.org/census/index.html?ed2street=1